# read_csv() requires len(names) == len(usecols)?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm using Python 3.6.3 and Pandas 0.21.1.

The following works as expected when `engine='c'`:

```
data = 'note,,\ncolA,colB,colC\n1,2,3\n4,5,6'
import io
import pandas as pd
filesim = io.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(filesim, 
                 names=['a','b','c'], 
                 header=1, 
                 usecols=['a'],
                 engine='c')
```

However, if I switch to `engine='python'` I trigger the error in this block of parsers.py (lines 2445-2451):

```
if names is not None:
    if ((self.usecols is not None and
                 len(names) != len(self.usecols)) or       <--- my problem
                (self.usecols is None and
                 len(names) != len(columns[0]))):
                raise ValueError('Number of passed names did not match '
                                 'number of header fields in the file')
```

It seems I'm triggering the error by providing 3 items for `names` and only 1 item for `usecols`. My questions are:

1. Isn't this the intended usage of `usecols` - to specify a subset of
   `names`? Why would we raise an error if their lengths are not equal?
2. Why doesn't the error message mentions anything about `usecols`?
3. Why does the python engine give me this problem, but the c engine works as expected?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not only works on `engine='c'` it also works without `engine` argument (`engine=None` as default)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the C engine works differently and needs to specify the delimiters.

Comment: The [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) does not mention any difference between engines with regards to `usecols`. I just tried adding a `sep=','` argument to my example code, and the result did not change for either engine.